# How to specify mail bounce address when using SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am sending a newsletter via Gmail's SMTP (actually, the SMTP depends on the mail's content, but let's use Gmail for this question).

My problem is, that bounced mails shall not return to the GMail account, but to another address. This address includes some VERP data to automatically detect outdated addresses.

What I know so far:

- Gmail restricts the FROM header (which is perfectly fine for me, we do not want to spoof anything).
- According to the SMTP specs, Gmail changes the Return-Path (or better: adds another one).
- The Error-to header is deprecated

Using PHPMailer, I already have set the envelope sender ($mail->Sender property), which is correctly sent during SMTP communication

```
2014-06-11 13:59:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<mailer+P=49276@myserver.de>
2014-06-11 13:59:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK ey16sm6579150wid.14 - gsmtp
```

So ... is there any other option to tell the receiving mailserver to send bounces to another address? And/or tell the Gmail SMTP server to send the bounces there, if they are directly generated by the SMTP server?

**UPDATE**

It seems that disregarding my envelope sender goes along with the known Gmail protocol violation of changing the From header (http://lee-phillips.org/gmailRewriting/). When trying the same with GMX, the email is simply refused until the envelope sender matches the GMX mail address corresponding to the login.

Does that mean, I have no chance to alter the address that bounces are sent to?

Comment: The envelope sender should be used for bounces, and end up in the `Return-Path:` header at the *receiving* end. Are you experiencing otherwise?

Comment: Granted, some braindead implementations will bounce to the `From:` address (or mailbomb their own postmaster, or some innocent third party...)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, in the email finally delivered, the envelope sender is in ONE (of two) Return-Path entries (probably, because I have set this header manually) - and the other (upper) Return-Path entry is the Gmail address that belongs to the SMTP usersname I use. If I use an invalid receiver address, the mail is bounced to the Gmail address. Possibly I shall check, if this is an exclusive Gmail problem...

Comment: Sounds like Gmail is overriding your envelope sender when relaying the message.

Comment: Just a little note: prior to the current release (5.2.8), [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) erroneously set the Return-Path header itself for SMTP sends. The Return-Path header should only be added by a receiver, not a sender.